# Calculate product of all following vector elements in R

Tags: r

I have some arbitrary vector such as

```
v <- seq(1,5)
```

For every index of `v` I now need to compute the product of all following elements of `v`.

Here, the result would be a vector `w=(5*4*3*2,5*4*3,5*4,5,1)` but I need a general algorithm for this. I am trying to avoid a loop (which is the obvious solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumprod` with `rev`:

```
c(rev(cumprod(rev(v[-1]))), 1)
#[1] 120  60  20   5   1
```